# why transition not working in margin-left property

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

could you please tell me why transition property is working in margin-left property.Actually on button click i am shifting margin-left property .I need some animation .

I can do with help of jQuery using animate function .But I want to do with css

i try like this

```
.outer li {
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transition: margin-left 2s; /* Safari */
    transition: margin-left 2s;
}
```

**JS**

```
function addToMarginLeft(elem, pixels) {
    var ml = parseFloat(elem.css('margin-left'));
   /* elem.animate({
    'margin-left': (ml + pixels) + 'px'
    },1000)*/
        elem.css('margin-left', (ml + pixels) + 'px');
  }
```

Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/uvsb6asa/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You added the transition to the wrong one:

working fiddle (has an issue with the initial next/back): https://jsfiddle.net/uvsb6asa/6/

Yours:

```
.outer ul {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

.outer li {
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transition: margin-left 2s; /* Safari */
    transition: margin-left 2s;
}
```

Correct:

```
.outer ul {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    -webkit-transition: margin-left 2s; /* Safari */
    transition: margin-left 2s;
}

.outer li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are adding transition to li but you are changing margin-left of ul.

You are doing:

```
.outer li {
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transition: margin-left 2s; /* Safari */
    transition: margin-left 2s;
}
```

Instead do this and it will work:

```
.outer li {
    display: inline-block;

}

.outer ul {
    -webkit-transition: margin-left 2s; /* Safari */
    transition: margin-left 2s;
}
```

Hope this helps